# Python library to process large files

Tags: python, performance

I'm looking for a Python library to process large files without performance problems. For example I want to transfer large files with hash calculating. Python faces memory problems with such processes. Is there any library that helps? (such pandas in data science)

Any help or documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? have you tried pickle ?

Comment: @lcrmorin my problem is performance.

Comment: What do you mean by performance ? time ? memory usage ?

Comment: memory and time.

Comment: You can read files by batches. For text files it is `file.readlines(chunk_size)` until you get EOF. It is also possible that your variables are too big and you could just reduce their size by using better data structures. You did not provide any code, so it is very hard to say, what is really happening. Also using numba and cython significantly increases performance.

Comment: @jojo If you are looking for algorithmic performance improvement, you should probably explain more clearly what you're doing. Otherwise there's no magic method in general, usually one has to sacrifice running time if one wants to save memory space and conversely use more memory if one wants to speed up the process.